# Querying a JSON array in rails psql Query

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a JSON

```
a = {
    cake: ["a","b","c","d"]
}
```

I need to query any value in a given values are present in the array
Like if the input is `["a","x"]` output should be `true`

```
if input is ["c","d"] then output is true

if input is ["x","z"] the n output is false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use intersection (&) and check if any of input is in the original array:

```
2.6.6 :002 > (a[:cake] & ['a','x']).any?
 => true 

2.6.6 :003 > (a[:cake] & ['x','z']).any?
 => false
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try to find common between json array and input array.

```
(a[:cake] & input_array).any?
```